# Python - Remove substring from string element in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, replace

Based on all my Googling, what I'm doing should work. Tl;dr - when I extracted some tables, it was formatted weird and some of them have 'Hide ' in the field name (there is a hide option on the table itself, probably just owing to lazy formatting that it's included in the field names).

I have the table sent to a big list, and am trying to `replace` the `'Hide '` with `''` but it's failing. I'm not sure if having consecutive `if` statements on the same indent line is causing an issue. Here is a snippet of the code I've tried (there is more above and below, but this is the section that is causing errors).

```py
my_list = ['Hide Physical Characteristics Eye Colour', 'brown', 'Hide Height', '180cm', 
'Hide Weight', '75kg']

#above the if statement, I set [val_idx] to my_list.index based on keywords in the list

if 'Hide Physical Characteristics Eye Colour' in my_list[val_idx]:
    my_list[val_idx] = 'Eye Colour'
if 'Hide ' in my_list[val_idx]:
    my_list[val_idx].replace('Hide ', '')
```

The reason I am not explicitly replacing the second if statement with a value (i.e. hair colour) is that there are several fields that have "hide" as the only undesirable part of the field name, rather than the longer 'Hide Physical Characteristics Eye Colour' which is the only long field name I am interested in replacing, and it just seemed more simplistic to make it more direct.

Based on what I know about python (only the basics and a bit more admittedly) this should all work. The first `if` statement does work, but the second one still gives the `'Hide '` in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable so `my_list[val_idx].replace('Hide ', '')` returns a new string which must be assigned back to the list

```
my_list[val_idx] = my_list[val_idx].replace('Hide ', '')
```

Comment: when I put it back in, will it go to the same index position ('height' back to the 2nd index, for example) because I need them to correspond to the values after (i.e. weight cannot be 180cm). I am sending them to a dict at the end of the function.

edit: this worked (it does maintain the position, I am just illiterate and it's early in the morning. thanks a ton!)

Comment: Yes it will be assigned to `my_list[val_idx]` so basically to `val_idx` position

Answer (score 0):

You could replace "Hide" with blank from all strings in the list first. And then remove "Physical Characteristics " which probably only applies to one element in the list.

```
list(map(lambda s: s.replace("Hide ", "").replace("Physical Characteristics ",""), my_list))
```

Output

```
['Eye Colour', 'brown', 'Height', '180cm', 'Weight', '75kg']
```

Comment: oh I like this one.

Answer (score 0):

This could do what you are looking for

```
my_list = ['Hide Physical Characteristics Eye Colour', 'brown', 'Hide Height', '180cm', 
'Hide Weight', '75kg']

for item in my_list:
    if 'Hide Physical Characteristics Eye Colour' == item:
        my_list[my_list.index(item)] = 'Eye Colour'
    else:
        my_list[my_list.index(item)].replace('Hide ', '')
```